# RandomForest decision confidence?

Tags: accord.net

I'm using accord.net's RandomForestLearning on some data, and have it predicting results correctly, but what I'd really like is a way to look at the decision confidence that goes along with the plain classification results?

Comment: This issue is being tracked at https://github.com/accord-net/framework/issues/613 and https://github.com/accord-net/framework/issues/603

Answer (score 0):

In the end I manually compute the confidence by summing the votes for each label from the component DecsionTrees and the dividing the maximal vote by the total votes. Would be nice if there was an official way, though.